# 2 different RBAC in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I am using yii2-basic. My project has 2 tables in DB, 1 is for mangagers, 1 is for users. Both contain profile data of users (username, password, email,...). But table Manager is for users who control the backend (I created 1 module called Backend). And table User is for users who use the web app, this table has many additional attributes, so I don't want to merge 2 tables into 1.

So can I separate into 2 different RBAC ? (manager_auth_item, manager_auth_role,... and user_auth_item, user_auth_role,...). How should I do that ?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I would think so. With two separate tables, I think it best to keep the roles separate.

Comment: @KarlWilbur yeah, but I think authManager will only work with auth_role, auth_item,... tables. How to config authManager for 2 different rbac ?